# Update multiple columns based on condition which approach is better in performance or is there any other better approach

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, query-optimization

```
drop table #source
create table #source
(
    userid int NULL,
    col1 nvarchar(max) NULL,
    col2 nvarchar(max) NULL,
    col3 nvarchar(max) NULL,
)
drop table #target
create table #target
(
    userid int NULL,
    col1 nvarchar(max) NULL,
    col2 nvarchar(max) NULL,
    col3 nvarchar(max) NULL,
    col4 nvarchar(max) NULL,
)
insert into #source values(1,'A','','B')
insert into #source values(2,'a',NULL,'b')

insert into #target values(1,NULL,'B','','extra')
insert into #target values(2,'aa',NULL,'b','extra')

select * from #source
select * from #target

update #target 
   set col1 = s.col1,
       col2 = s.col2,
       col3 = s.col3
   from #target t
   inner join #source s
     on s.userid = t.userid
where 
    s.col1 <> t.col1 or s.col1 is null and t.col1 is not null or s.col1 is not null and t.col1 is null
OR  s.col2 <> t.col2 or s.col2 is null and t.col2 is not null or s.col2 is not null and t.col2 is null
OR  s.col3 <> t.col3 or s.col3 is null and t.col3 is not null or s.col3 is not null and t.col3 is null


update #target 
   set 
       col1 = CASE WHEN s.col1 <> t.col1 or s.col1 is null and t.col1 is not null or s.col1 is not null and t.col1 is null THEN s.col1 ELSE t.col1 END,
       col2 = CASE WHEN s.col2 <> t.col2 or s.col2 is null and t.col2 is not null or s.col2 is not null and t.col2 is null THEN s.col2 ELSE t.col2 END,
       col3 = CASE WHEN s.col3 <> t.col3 or s.col3 is null and t.col3 is not null or s.col3 is not null and t.col3 is null THEN s.col3 ELSE t.col3 END
   from #target t
   inner join #source s
     on s.userid = t.userid
```

I want to update only if the value is not the same for a given column and also considering the performance. Any insight is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance. After looking at many thread, came to know SQL internally does not perform update if the values are same.

Comment: An `update` will still cause an update if the values are the same; haven't tested it in latest versions but I'm pretty convinced that an update doesn't care if the value changes or not, it will write the new version to disk regardless. Anyway, the easiest way to figure out what works best is by simply trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that both tables are (clustered) indexed on user_id.
2. Add some brackets with all those `AND` and `OR`, if only for readability.

Your first `update` will do what you expect it to do: only update the records where there is a difference. The second `update` will update ALL (matching on userid) records.

Performance-wise the first one will probably be a lot easier for the system as the actual number of records can be significantly lower than the total number of records.

In an edge case you could argue that *IF* all records require updating, then the more simple `INNER JOIN` from the second version could be slightly easier on the system, but in that case you can get rid of the `CASE..WHEN..THEN` construction because frankly it doesn't really add anything: when you set a field to a value it doesn't matter at all if said value is the same value as before or not.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to read my post. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html  line "If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it." please take a look at this and share your thoughts. Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Ah. The question did not mention this was MySQL. Given the sql-server tag I assumed it would be MSSQL. I have little to no experience with MySQL and it could well be that said RDBMS handles this differently. Interesting. I now wonder how/if this affects the affected rowcount... Nevertheless, I still think you can get rid of the `CASE..WHEN..THEN` construction as assigning the new value directly will have the exact same effect. (PS: the linked article also shows that `UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;` behaves rather exotically.. scary but we learn every day =)

Comment: All in all, my best advice remains that the only sure way to figure this is out is by doing some testing Simply make sure your volumes are' representative'. What works great on 100 rows might act rather differently on 100k rows.

Comment: Thanks again. my apology for the confusion. I should not have assumed it might be the same implementation under the hood in MSSQl. I could not find any in MSSQL documentation so far. I tried with 250k rows with 11 columns. case statement took 10 seconds and 7 seconds  without case statements.